# How to understand traverse, traverseU and traverseM

Tags: scala, scalaz

I am confused about the usage case about traverse, traverseU and traverseM, I searched it in the scalaz website, the simple code example:

```
 def sum(x: Int) = x + 1

 List(1,2,3).traverseU(sum)
```

it looks like it is similar to (map and aggregate):

```
List(1,2,3).map(sum).reduceLeft(_ + _)
```

I think it is more than that for traverseU, I just wonder what is the difference between those 3 method, it would be better I will have some sample code to show the difference

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`sequence` is used to *gather together applicative effects*. More concretely, it lets you "flip" `F[G[A]]` to `G[F[A]]`, provided `G` is `Applicative` and `F` is `Traversable`. So we can use it to "pull together" a bunch of `Applicative` effects (note all `Monad`s are `Applicative`):

```
List(Future.successful(1), Future.successful(2)).sequence : Future[List[Int]]
// = Future.successful(List(1, 2))
List(4.set("abc"), 5.set("def")).sequence : Writer[String, List[Int]]
// = List(4, 5).set("abcdef")
```

`traverse` is equivalent to `map` then `sequence`, so you can use it when you have a function that returns an `Applicative` and you want to just get a single instance of your `Applicative` rather than a list of them:

```
def fetchPost(postId: Int): Future[String]
//Fetch each post, but we only want an overall `Future`, not a `List[Future]`
List(1, 2).traverse[Future, String](fetchPost): Future[List[String]]
```

`traverseU` is the same operation as `traverse`, just with the types expressed differently so that the compiler can infer them more easily.

```
def logConversion(s: String): Writer[Vector[String], Int] =
  s.toInt.set(Vector(s"Converted $s"))
List("4", "5").traverseU(logConversion): Writer[Vector[String], List[Int]]
// = List("4", "5").map(logConversion).sequence
// = List(4.set("Converted 4"), 5.set("Converted 5")).sequence
// = List(4, 5).set(Vector("Converted 4", "Converted 5"))
```

`traverseM(f)` is equivalent to `traverse(f).map(_.join)`, where `join` is the scalaz name for `flatten`. It's useful as a kind of "lifting flatMap":

```
def multiples(i: Int): Future[List[Int]] =
  Future.successful(List(i, i * 2, i * 3))
List(1, 10).map(multiples): List[Future[List[Int]]] //hard to work with
List(1, 10).traverseM(multiples): Future[List[Int]]
// = List(1, 10).traverse(multiples).map(_.flatten)
// = List(1, 10).map(multiples).sequence.map(_.flatten)
// = List(Future.successful(List(1, 2, 3)), Future.successful(List(10, 20, 30)))
//     .sequence.map(_.flatten)
// = Future.successful(List(List(1, 2, 3), List(10, 20, 30))).map(_.flatten)
// = Future.successful(List(1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30))
```

Comment: thanks, I upvote, so I just wonder you mentioned that the difference between traverse and traverseU is the type inference, is this only difference, because as far as I am concerned, I will only use traverseU instead of traverse

Comment: Yes, that's the only difference. (Technically it uses an extra parameter to perform the inference, but I'd expect the JVM to optimize this away). In the case where `traverseU` *doesn't* infer the type parameters and you need to specify them by hand (or if you're writing generic code where the type you're traversing is itself a type parameter), it's easier to do with `traverse` (which doesn't have the inference helper), but I think that's the only case where you'd ever want to use `traverse` rather than `traverseU`

Comment: BTW, I think the code should be Future.now instead of Future.successful, because the previous one is from scalaz, so it will have implicit value, but the later one from standard library does not have implicit resolution

Comment: I believe there are instances for the standard library `Future` if you have the appropriate imports in scope (from somewhere in `scalaz.std`).