# Composition of Conditional Futures in Scala

Tags: scala, asynchronous, monads, future

I have some code that works for a simple case (2 Futures) but I can't quite find the way to generalize it for an unlimited number of Futures.

What I want to do is create some code that calls a future and, when that future is completed, call another one, and when this one is completed call another one, and so on.

I need the result of each call to be completed before calling the next one because I may not need to call it again (this is my stopping condition).

> I know this can be solved explicitly with recursion, but I would like, if at all possible, a solution using for comprehensions and/or folds. I feel there must be a solution like that but I can't write it correctly.

Here's a a function that generates a a list of two random ints

```
def nextValue: Future[List[Int]] = Future{
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  val num1 = Random.nextInt(10)
  val num2 = Random.nextInt(10)
  List(num1,num2)
}
```

Now I would like to compose infinitely many such futures and join them  all at the end (a single future of a list)

> I'm just calling await.result for testing purposes

This works for 2 levels, but how to generalize it for N calls?

```
Await.result({
  nextValue.flatMap{ value1 =>
    nextValue.map{ value2 =>
      value1 ++ value2
    }
  }
},1.minute)
```

Comment: If each `Future` is launched only after the previous completes, what's the point of using `Future` at all?  Could you wrap a `fold` or `Stream` in a single `Future` which will complete when the stopping condition has been met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future.sequence((0 to 100).map(_ => nextValue)).map(_.flatten)
```

Usage:

```
scala> Future.sequence((0 to 100).map(_ => nextValue)).map(_.flatten)
res3: scala.concurrent.Future[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@692e028d

scala> Await.result(res3, duration.Duration.Inf)
res4: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(5, 4, 3, 0, 4, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 4, 6, 2, 7, 4, 9, 8, 8, 6, 9, 1, 4, 5, 5, 8, 2, 2, 7, 6, 0, 5, 6, 6, 5, 9, 6, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1, 8, 4, 6, 7, 5, 1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 1, 5, 9, 4, 5, 0, 1, 8, 5, 0, 0, 7, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0, 4, 1, 6, 3, 8, 2, 1, 3, 5, 5, 8, 3, 6, 1, 3, 2, 9, 4, 9, 4, 7, 5, 7, 8, 7, 9, 5, 2, 5, 0, 2, 5, 6, 8, 6, 2, 3, 2, 0, 8, 9, 3, 9, 2, 7, 5, 1, 7, 1, 1, 8, 6, 8, 0, 5, 5, 6, 0, 8, 8, 3, 6, 4, 2, 7, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 8, 7, 3, 3, 5, 1, 6, 3, 3, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 1, 9, 9, 8, 1, 1, 5, 8, 1, 1, 7, 6, 3, 2, 5, 0, 4, 3, 0, 9, 9, 1, 2, 0, 3, 6, 2, 6, 8, 6, 6, 3, 9, 7, 1, 3, 5, 9, 6, 5, 6, 2)
```

Or with scalaz/cats:

```
//import scalaz._,Scalaz._
// --or--
//import cats.syntax.traverse._
//import cats.std.list._
//import cats.std.future._

(0 to 100).toList.traverseM(_ => nextValue)
```

Eplanation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26606232/1809978):

> traverseM(f) is equivalent to traverse(f).map(_.join), where join is
>   the scalaz name for flatten. It's useful as a kind of "lifting
>   flatMap":

---

If you want some condition and still need to stay async, you can use fs2:

```
import fs2._
import fs2.util._

def nextValue: Task[List[Int]] = Task.delay{
  import scala.util.Random
  val num1 = Random.nextInt(10)
  val num2 = Random.nextInt(10)
  if(num1 > 5) List(num1,num2) else List()
}
Stream.repeatEval(nextValue).takeWhile(_.size > 0).runLog.map(_.flatten).unsafeRun
```

https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/blob/series/0.9/docs/guide.md

The same can be achieved with Iteratees:

Cats: https://github.com/travisbrown/iteratee
or scalaz-iteratee package

Generally speaking, you can't implement this with `fold` because it's actually `unfold` and there is no good support for unfold in scala as standard library's `Stream` can't generalize over a Monad/ApplicativeFunctor (like `EnumeratorT` does) - you can only check a condition by doing `Await.result` on every unfolding step.

Comment: I thought the OP was looking for a collection of length determined by an exit condition, i.e. get `nextValue` until we get the terminus result.

Comment: you're right, I didn't read the question carefully - will update my answer

Comment: yeah... I would like to test the result of getNext to see if it's valid and terminate if it isn't. Is this possible?

Comment: I've added solution with external library, now will add classic solution

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't think of any implementation using unfold in standard library without `Await.result` on every step. I've added an explanation why.